# Ionic 1 images not displaying

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

am currently having an issue with my online images not showing on my ionic 1 app. The url i get back is:
"http://localhost:8100/api//users/assetpackages/client/uploads/8e0c38c538eae5fb42408e6042e8b64a.jpeg".
I get a error code of 404 Not Found.

The code am using is:
`<img ng-src="{{apiUrl}}/{{user.profile}}" alt="">`

Comment: there is a **double** slash: `...8100/api//users...`, check where it comes from and remove it

Answer (score 1):

Possibly `{{apiUrl}}/{{user.profile}}` should be `{{apiUrl}}{{user.profile}}` without the slash in the middle.